# Sonar fails to show Build stability information from Jenkins, though Jenkins claims data has been collected

Tags: build, jenkins, sonarqube

Sonar fails to show Build stability information from Jenkins, though Jenkins claims data has been collected

It has not worked at any point for me.

The process I use:

1. Run the project build on Jenkins.
2. Wait for Jenkins to finish with success.
3. Go to sonar and reload the project.
4. There is no build server information.
5. Please see below for part of the Jenkins output which states that is has retrieved 6 builds.

   - Is there a way in which that I can check that the plugin is being loaded?
   - (I can't get tech dept to work either).
   - What is 'Global/Project/Module Settings -> Build Stability' How do I find it?
   - (Step 4 on http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Build+Stability+Plugin)

Any ideas on where I can start looking for the problem?

- X86, 32bit
- OS: Ubuntu 11.10
- Sonar: 2.13.1
- Build stability plugin: 1.1.2
- Jenkins: 1.424.3
- mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.58, for debian-linux-gnu (i686) using readline 6.2
- java version "1.6.0_23"
- OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11pre) (6b23~pre11-0ubuntu1.11.10.2)

Jenkins build output:

```
[INFO] [20:33:29.673] Sensor org.sonar.plugins.buildstability.BuildStabilitySensor@1858aa4...
[INFO] [20:33:29.673] CI URL: Hudson:http://localhost:8080/job/AgileTest/
[INFO] [20:33:30.944] Retrieved 6 builds since Thu Feb 02 20:33:29 CET 2012
[INFO] [20:33:30.957] Sensor org.sonar.plugins.buildstability.BuildStabilitySensor@1858aa4 done: 1284 ms
```

Comment: Ahh, found it.

I had to log in to sonar, then I was able to add the Build stability, and tech debt.

Login info at: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Log+into+Son

Comment: please add this as an answer (which you can accept later)